Add a way to hide site disclaimers
Issue: Site disclaimers sometimes take most of the page on mobile devices (example), and they appear on all questions, if the site has a disclaimer.
Feature request: Add a way to hide site disclaimers.

For example, some sort of way to collapse/temporarily hide them? That way, they could easily be unhidden/expanded later if desired.

@V2Blast yes, collapse/temporarily hide them. (I'd prefer hide them)

Maybe another option is a button that says "I read and understand the risks/accept" and clicking the button hides the disclaimer and stores the user's acknowledgement so the system knows not to show it any more.

@CaveJohnson that'd be perfect.
